# input inline edit clickOutside

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i'm trying to inline edit an input this way, i wrote a clickOutside directive and it works fine but in my example when i click to edit `editMode` becomes true and immediately input is shown and `clickOutside` triggers and makes the `editMode` false, so this cause my edit click not work :

```
<span *ngIf="!editMode" (click)="edit(); editMode = true"></span>
<input *ngIf="editMode" (clickOutside)="save(); editMode = false">
```

how can i resolve this problem?
thanks in advance.

my **clickOutside directive**:

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, Output, EventEmitter, HostListener} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[clickOutside]'
})
export class ClickOutsideDirective {
    constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {
    }

    @Output()
    public clickOutside = new EventEmitter<MouseEvent>();

    @HostListener('document:click', ['$event', '$event.target'])
    public onClick(event: MouseEvent, targetElement: HTMLElement): void {
        if (!targetElement) {
            return;
        }

        const clickedInside = this.elementRef.nativeElement.contains(targetElement);
        if (!clickedInside) {
            this.clickOutside.emit(event);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is `(blur)` can't help you instead of seperate directive? Just curious to know...

Comment: Why not wrap the elements in an `inline-block` styled `div`, and move the `(clickOutside)` to the wrapper div?

Comment: @Javascript_Lover may you explain more? when to use blur?

Comment: @user184994 good solution i will try and notify you.

Comment: @fatemefazli you have to stop the event bubbling for click event, then it works... I've posted the answer, please check once.

Comment: @user184994 i tried your solution and it works fine, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<span *ngIf="!editMode" (click)="edit($event); editMode = true">Click to edit</span>
<input *ngIf="editMode" (clickOutside)="save(); editMode = false">
```

**Typescript**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  editMode = false;

  edit(event) {
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    console.log(this.editMode);
  }

  save() {
    console.log(this.editMode);
  }

}
```

Comment: Why not just `stopPropagation`?

Comment: @yurzui anything is fine :-) stopPropagation also works. There is no special purpose that I am keeping `event.stopImmediatePropagation` but anyways there is difference between them.

Comment: I've created the [stackblitz](https://angular-v3otvm.stackblitz.io) here

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to like below:

```
  <span *ngIf="!editMode" (click)="edit();editMode = true" >span</span>
  <input *ngIf="editMode" (clickOutside)="save();editMode = false;"  
           [delayClickOutsideInit]="true">
```

Here we are adding `[delayClickOutsideInit]="true"`

As per [ng-click-outside documentation](https://github.com/arkon/ng-click-outside), it

> Delays the initialization of the click outside handler. This may help
>   for items that are conditionally shown

Comment: but 'delayClickOutsideInit' isn't a known property of 'input' .

Comment: Try [attr.delayClickOutsideInit]="true". I tested above snippet on stackblitz - it seemed to have work just fine.

Comment: I tried with version 4.0.0 of ng-click-outside - which version are you using? Or let us know which library are you using?  (clickOutside) is not available in Angular by default - one needs external library or would write such directive oneself

Comment: i don't use  ng-click-outside, i wrote my own clickOutside directive, updated the question.

Comment: Oh - in that case - your code may not be handling the scenario.  May be look at code of ng-click-outside and try to figure out how they solved this issue.  https://github.com/arkon/ng-click-outside/blob/master/src/click-outside.directive.ts

Answer (score 1):

You could delay the setting of `editMode`, to make sure that the click event is completed before the input element is displayed:

```
<span *ngIf="!editMode" (click)="setEditMode()"></span>
```

with the method:

```
public setEditMode(): void {
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.edit();
    this.editMode = true;
  }, 50);
}
```

Comment: thank u it works but unfortunately i can't use setTimeout.